# _mm_extract_epi8(...) intrinsic that takes a non-literal integer as argument

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

I've lately been using the SSE intrinsic `int _mm_extract_epi8 (__m128i src, const int ndx)` that, according to the reference "extracts an integer byte from a packed integer array element selected by index". This is exactly what I want.

However, I determine the index via a `_mm_cmpestri` on a `_m128i` that performs a packed comparison of string data with explicit lengths and generates the index. The range of this index is 0..16 where 0..15 represents a valid index and 16 means that no index was found. Now to extract the integer at the index position I thought of doing the following:

```
const int index = _mm_cmpestri(...);
if (index >= 0 && index < 16) {
  int intAtIndex = _mm_extract_epi8(..., index);
}
```

This leaves us with the gcc (-O0) compiler error:

error: selector must be an integer constant in the range 0..15

A nasty way around this issue is to have a `switch` on the index and a `_mm_extract_epi8` call for each index in range 0..15. My question is if there is a better/nicer way that I don't see.

Update: with -O3 optimization, there is no compilation error; still with -O0 though.

Comment: You could just load the byte from the same 16-bytes vector you feed into _mm_cmpestri

Comment: You get an index from a `pcmpestri`. `pextrb` requires an actual constant as the index, not a "well I say this is a constant but actually you can't encode this as an immediate operand", so how does this even work?

Comment: @Maratyszcza: yes you could, but using the switch and _mm_extract_epi8 is faster than accessing the origin. I assume because _m128i is already pointing to the loaded register.

Comment: @harold: yes, true. That's why I'm asking for an alternative. I know I can do the switch, but I wanted to know if there is already an abstraction for that. Would be nicer to have an intrinsic that does that but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @muehlbau well you could shuffle the index-th element into position with `pshufb` and then take the zeroth element. Or you could generate a mask instead of an index, AND it with the data, and then take since it's only a byte you can use `psadbw` (other argument should be zero) to take the horizontal sum to put that byte in position zero. They're all ugly hacks, but then, you're not really supposed to want this.

Comment: If you're going to go for something as nasty as a switch, you might as well just use a union hack. It's a lot cleaner, but not necessarily more expensive.

Comment: @Mysticial: wut is a union hack in this case?

Comment: You union the `__m128i` type with a `char[16]`. Then access the char array by index. That said, it's generally not recommended because it's slow. But it's probably still better than switch statement.

Comment: I've tried @harold's `pshufb` approach and @Mystical's union hack approach. On both, an Intel i7/AMD Bulldozer machine the switch and union hack have comparable performance; `pshufb` was a bit slower – overall all 3 possibilities have comparable performance. Union hack is probably the most readable. Thanks for your suggestions guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to summarize and close the question.

We discussed 3 options to extract a byte at index i in [0..15] from a `_m128i sse` where i cannot be reduced to a literal at compile time:

1) Switch & `_mm_extract_epi8`: have a `switch` over i and a case for each i in [0..15] that does a `_mm_extract_epi8(sse,i)`; works as i now is a compile-time literal.

2) Union hack: have a `union SSE128i { __m128i sse; char[16] array; }`, initialize it as `SSE128i sse = { _mm_loadu_si128(...) }` and access the byte at index i with `sse.array[i]`.

3) Shuffle ith element to position 0 and `_mm_extract_epi8`: use `_mm_shuffle_epi8(sse,_mm_set1_epi8(i))` to shuffle the ith element to position 0; extract it with `_mm_extract_epi8(sse,0)`.

Evaluation: I benchmarked the three options on an Intel Sandy Bridge and a AMD Bulldozer architecture. The switch option won by a small margin. If someone's interested I can post more detailed numbers and the benchmark setup.

**Update: Evaluation**
Benchmark setup: parse each byte of a 1GB file. For certain special bytes, increase a counter. Use `_mm_cmpistri` to find the index of a special byte; then "extract" the byte using one of the three methods mentioned and do a case distinction in which the counters are incremented. Code was compiled using GCC 4.6 with `-std=c++0x -O3 -march=native`.

For each method, the benchmark was run 25 times on a Sandy Bridge machine. Results (mean and std. dev. of running time in seconds):

Switch and extract:
Mean: 1071.45
Standard deviation: 2.72006

Union hack:
Mean: 1078.61
Standard deviation: 2.87131

Suffle and extract from position 0:
Mean: 1079.32
Standard deviation: 2.69808

The differences are marginal. I haven't had a chance to look at the generated asm yet. Might be interesting to see the difference though. For now I can't release the full code of the benchmark as it contains non-public sources. If I have time I'll extract these and post the sources.

Comment: Just added them to the answer.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not really happy with that benchmark - could you do it with less data? Say, half L3-size? Should show the difference more clearly.

Comment: Since you already have the bytes in memory where you initially loaded a vector from, your best bet is probably to index that again, instead of encouraging the compiler to store/reload a `__m128i` with a union.  Was your `switch` test running repeatedly with the same index, so it could branch-predict well?  Microbenchmarking often doesn't reflect reality when you compare branchy vs. branchless, unless you *really* randomize your microbenchmark with a long pattern length.

Comment: Related: [How to use \_mm\_extract\_epi8 function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54492956)/ if you're *looping* over all elements, you definitely want to just store to an array for that many elements.